# Best OOP JavaScript practice for security

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, namespaces

**Question at the bottom**

**Building up to the question**
I've heard that global variables are security risks to code security, and that there are different coding choices available to make a variable from one function to be visible and usable by another function, e.g., "function A to be visible to function B; or, a variable of Function A to be passed and usable within function B."

**Question:**
If client-side wasn't an issue, what is the best OOP structure or practice in JavaScript syntax, that keeps things encapsulated and adds the greatest security from having your variables exposed to manipulation? Just a good OOP practice question.

Comment: you can just use Doug's privileged pattern to provide public methods, properties, and events that affect private vars defined inside the constructor or factory. Object.freeze, Object.defineProperty, and Object.seal can all provide property access security in modern browsers.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is really never secure since it runs entirely client side with everything visible and open to manipulation. 
I tend to manage scope using closures to limit scope to what's appropriate for my different code blocks. However, this does not offer any security advantages

I favor the closure model since it offers good encapsulation for internal methods and variables. You can define functionality without worrying about it "polluting" the global space and potentially interfering with other functionality.

As far as I'm concerned, there is no pattern that will protect you against manipulation. The best advice is to not trust JavaScript variables and always use proper server side validation before accepting their values.

Comment: If client-side wasn't an issue, what would be 1. good OOP structure, and 2., protect variables from manipulation?